# How can I fill / replace only %100 transparent pixels with a selected color in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, image-processing

There are countless examples to add background layer

That is not what I want because if you have semi transparent pixels that breaks their color

What I want to achieve is only replacing %100 transparent pixels with selected color

Example image

You see there are semi transparent pixels around antennas. I want to replace only if %100 transparent not a single visible pixel color

[image]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159849/how-to-select-all-transparent-pixels-in-a-layer-and-replace-them-with-another-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the thumbnail image in the layers panel to select all colored pixels
- Inverse to select all transparent pixels
- Enter Quickmask mode
- Use menu *Image > Adjustments > Threshold* with a value of 255
  on the Quickmask channel
- Exit Quickmask, and all the 100% transparent pixels will be selected.

Comment: ok i made it work you are great ty